# Ungrouping a Raster image

Tags: raster

I'd like to separate this raster image into 4 individual pieces. Any tips on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What software are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Photoshop, use the Polygonal Lasso tool (L) to select between the white spaces. Hit CTRL+J to separate each shape to individual layers. Go back to the original layer and do this for each individual piece. You should end up with 4 separate layers, one for each section of the chart.

Comment: That works a treat. Thank you